# how to return tightly packed storage values in assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

I have a contract with 2 tightly packed values in storage slot1, how do I return the second address value with assembly?

```
Contract MyContract{
  bool a;
  address b;
  
  function getAddress() public returns (address){
    assembly {
      mstore(mload(0x40), sload(1))
      return(0x40, 32)    
    }
  }
}
```

as this will return the packed value of both a+b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the values are similar to follows

```
  bool a = true;
  address b=0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
```

then the slot 0 value would be

```
>> 0x00000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc401
```

Right most digit would be the bool value.

To extract the address,

1. load the slot 0
2. extract only the address and shifting right

```
contract MyContract{
  bool a = true;
  address b=0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
  
  function getAddress() public view returns (address){
    assembly {
        mstore(0x40, shr(8, and(sload(0),0x00000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00)))
       return(0x40, 0x60)    
    }
  }

}
```

and operation zero out the bool and possible other values gives a result as follows

```
>> 0x00000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc400
```

Then 8 bits are shifted right to get the result as follows

```
>> 0x0000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

Comment: perfect, thanks for your answer, i think when you say shift right 8 bytes, you actually mean bits right?

Comment: sorry, yes and corrected it